# How to use "select into" to different table with different column names

Tags: ms-access, select

I need to add rows (if matching with the criteria) in MS-Access to an existing table, but the column names are not matching.

For example:

source table:

```
name      hardware    age
----------  
john      pc          42 
peter     notebook    23 
carl      console     34
```

destination table:

```
User      tool        age
----------  
george    tablet      25
john      pc          42 
peter     notebook    23 
carl      console     34
```

I need to add new rows to the end of the destination table. However, the column names are different.
Please, someone help.

Comment: Are you doing this with the query designer? or with an SQL statement?

Answer (score 2):

You can use `INSERT INTO.. SELECT .. FROM`

```
INSERT INTO yourDestinationTable (User, tool, age)
SELECT name, hardware, age
FROM yourSourceTable
```